# How to set default group depending on the site

Tags: liferay

I have two sites (`site1` and `site2`) and two groups (`group1` and `group2`). I have `Sign In` Liferay's portlet on both sites. I want that If user registers by `Sign In` portlet on `site1` then user is assigned to `group1` and if user registers by `Sign In` portlet on `site2` then user is assigned to `group2`.

How to do it?

===EDIT===

I tried write hook with struts action but it does not work for me.

liferay-hook.xml:

```
<hook>
    <struts-action>
        <struts-action-path>/login/create_account</struts-action-path>
        <struts-action-impl>com.mypackage.CreateAccountAction</struts-action-impl>
    </struts-action>
</hook>
```

CreateAccountAction.java:

```
package com.mypackage;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletConfig;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.struts.BaseStrutsPortletAction;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.struts.StrutsPortletAction;

public class CreateAccountAction extends BaseStrutsPortletAction {
    public void processAction(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
            PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("CreateAccountAction");
        originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(originalStrutsPortletAction,
                portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);
    }
}
```

Click on Create Account cases:

```
12:25:38,177 ERROR [http-bio-8078-exec-126][PortletRequestProcessor:466] Forward does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write hook to override struts-action(`/login/create_account`) responsible for creating account. [Overriding and Adding Struts Actions](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/override-and-add-struts-actions-with-hook-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en)

In code, perform Original struts action's processAction (`com.liferay.portlet.login.action.CreateAccountAction`), after that check for `SessionErrors` object, it should be empty.(Because then only user will have been created)

If `SessionErrors` is empty, then get User object by emailaddress(get emailaddress from request parameter)  and current group from `themeDisplay` object.

Having User object and current group object you can easily assign user to group by `GroupLocalServiceUtil.addUserGroups(userId, groupId)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a begginer in Liferay and I can't use your answer. I edited my question to show my attempt to use your answer. Could you write some sample code? Thanks.

Comment: Please also override render method also to avoid this error.

Comment: I don't know how I can get User from `themeDisplay`. `themeDisplay.getUser()` returns some default liferay user with mail `default@liferay.com`. I don't need current group, I need `group1` id or `group2` id and I should find groups by name.

Comment: As you are a GUEST user while you register,its giving default@liferay.com(guest user). You have to get emailAddress from request and then using `UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress`, you can get user.